# How to drawing on JFrame

Tags: java, swing

```
public class MouseTracker extends JPanel{
static List<Double> xL = new ArrayList<Double>();
static List<Double> yL = new ArrayList<Double>();

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1920,1080);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    Timer time = new Timer();
    time.schedule(new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            String coords = getCoords();
            System.out.println(coords);
        }
    }, 0, 250);
}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> y = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    x.add(xL.get(xL.size() - 1).intValue());
    x.add(xL.get(xL.size() - 2).intValue());

    y.add(yL.get(yL.size() - 1).intValue());
    y.add(yL.get(yL.size() - 2).intValue());

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.setColor(Color.red);
    g2d.drawLine(x.get(0), y.get(0), x.get(1), y.get(1));
}


public static String getCoords(){
    double xCoord = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX();
    double yCoord = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY();

    xL.add(xCoord);
    yL.add(yCoord);

    String coords = Double.toString(xCoord) + " : " + Double.toString(yCoord);
    return coords;
}
}
```

Im trying to write a program to create a visualization of mouse movement.

The above code is grabing the mouse coords fine the problem is I am not sure as to how to invoke the paintComponent in order to draw on the frame.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a common project. You can find my implementations here: http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/ex/ (PaintArea and PaintArea2). In short, the way to do this is to create an Image, paint on that in your mouse events, and then paint the image in paintComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to add a new instance of `MouseTracker` to the contentpane:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

frame.getContentPane().add(new MouseTracker());

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Then call repaint in the timer:

```
Timer time = new Timer();
time.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        String coords = getCoords();
        System.out.println(coords);
        frame.getContentPane().repaint();
    }
}, 0, 250);
```

So the whole code will look like this (where the lines are persistent):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MouseTracker extends JPanel {
    static ArrayList<Double> xL = new ArrayList<Double>();
    static ArrayList<Double> yL = new ArrayList<Double>();

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.getContentPane().add(new MouseTracker());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Timer time = new Timer();
        time.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                String coords = getCoords();
                System.out.println(coords);
                frame.getContentPane().repaint();
            }
        }, 0, 250);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> y = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < xL.size(); i++) {

            x.add(xL.get(i).intValue());
            y.add(yL.get(i).intValue());

        }

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setColor(Color.red);

        for (int i = 0; i < xL.size() - 1; i++) {

            g2d.drawLine(x.get(i), y.get(i), x.get(i + 1), y.get(i + 1));

        }

    }

    public static String getCoords() {
        double xCoord = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX();
        double yCoord = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY();

        xL.add(xCoord);
        yL.add(yCoord);

        String coords = Double.toString(xCoord) + " : "
                + Double.toString(yCoord);
        return coords;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that has worked. However the lines are not persistent, is there a way to make them persistent?

Comment: @user3556152 The easy way: Don't call `super.paintComponent(g);`

Comment: @user3556152, No, you should always call super.paintComponent(). A component should always be responsible for painting its complete state. If you have multiple lines then every time you add a new line you should add the line to an ArrayList. Then the painting code needs to be changed to iterate through the ArrayList to repaint every line. See the `DrawOnComponent` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working example of this approach.

Comment: @camickr That's why I said "easy way" - But thanks for pointing it out! I've edited my answer, I hope it is more correct now.